# NSURLRequest + JSON : Bad URL

Tags: json, nsurlrequest

I'm new to the iOS development.

I'm using the following code to send a request the server and get response synchronously.

My request contains JSON object. When I run on simulator I got error "Bad URL".

Please help me to solve this issue.

```
NSString *regUrlWithJson = @"https://dso.mpl.com/reg?json={\"operation\":\"login\",\"contactEmail\":\"abc@rt.com\",\"password\":\"e3dba1bbfab020a2eb105c69405a7766\",\"SSO\":\"true\",\"service\":\"lp\",\"sig\":\"true\",\"url\":\"mpl\"}";

NSLog(regUrlWithJson);
NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:regUrlWithJson]];

NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                  error:&error];

if (error != nil)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:string delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Got the answer. Need to encode the URL.

 NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:
                     [regUrlWithJson stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    
    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theUrl];

Answer (score 0):

`regUrlWithJson` is not valid URL. This is the reason